# Remove line from php file using sed

Tags: php, unix, sed

Website got hacked and it puts code at top line of every php page before the opening `<?php` tag, i want to use sed to remove it from all files with one command.

It starts with

```
<?php if(!isset($GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"]))
```

and ends with

```
-1; ?><?php
```

I think this is caused by old version of mailpoet (wysija) wordpress plugin.
http://blog.sucuri.net/2014/10/wordpress-websites-continue-to-get-hacked-via-mailpoet-plugin-vulnerability.html

I tried the answers of these two, but solutions isnt removing these lines for me. I would appreciate any and all help as im no expert with unix commands.

[Mass removal of malicious line from php files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285186/mass-removal-of-malicious-line-from-php-files)

[Removing a string in a PHP file with Start and End](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25996752/removing-a-string-in-a-php-file-with-start-and-end)

///EDIT

Sample input i used, supposed to remove the line from file, but file stays same, doesnt print anything to terminal

```
sed -i '1 s/^<\?php if(!isset($GLOBALS\[.*-1; \?>//' *.php
```

Once i have this command working i want to combine it with find command to run on whole server

Comment: could you post a sample input along with the expected output?

Comment: Don't you have a GIT Repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this GNU sed command,

```
sed -r '1s/^<\?php if\(!isset\(\$GLOBALS\[.*-1; \?>//' *.php
```

Add inline edit option `i` to save the changes made.

```
sed -ri '1s/^<\?php if\(!isset\(\$GLOBALS\[.*-1; \?>//' *.php
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name "*.php" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -ri '1s/^<\?php if\(!isset\(\$GLOBALS\[.*-1; \?>//' *.php
```

Comment: Why did you create a second account and answered the question [*again*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31742149)?